# Problem creating a simple menu function on fortran 95 using a module

Tags: function, module, fortran, fortran95

I am just beginning to create a menu function on a module and I'm getting a fatal error, too many errors. I suspect this is probably due to one small mistake instead of multiple since the code is so simple as of right now.

Someone have any ideas?

Below is what I have so far. Obviously I have just begun, but already I am surprised why there is a problem. Thanks so much!

Also I'm a bit new to modules so I'm just curious can you tell if this is how to compile it? g95 themenu.f95 -o ba ??

Thanks.

```
 MODULE themenu
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER:: choices, opt
    opt=choices()

     CONTAINS

    INTEGER FUNCTION choices ()
    INTEGER:: opt

    DO
        PRINT*, "1: Add an item manually"
        PRINT*, "2: Add item(s) from a file"
        PRINT*, "3: Add random item from list of top ten list"
        PRINT*, "4: Print list with totals"
        PRINT*, "5: Sort list alphabetically"
        PRINT*, "6: Sort list by price"
        PRINT*, "7: Write list to file"
        PRINT*, "8: EXIT"
        PRINT*, " "
        PRINT*, "Please make your selection (enter a number): "
        READ*, opt
        IF (opt>=1 .AND. opt<=8)EXIT
        PRINT*, "INVALID CHOICE. MUST BE A NUMBER 1-8. PLEASE TRY AGAIN!"
    END DO
    choices=opt
    END FUNCTION
    END MODULE
```

Thanks! The Program that uses this module looks someting like this so far:

```
PROGRAM listman
USE themenu
IMPLICIT NONE
END PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have assignment statements in a module, only data type specifications and a `CONTAINS` section with procedures.

```
MODULE themenu
CONTAINS
    INTEGER FUNCTION choices ()
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER:: opt
    ....
    END FUNCTION
END MODULE

PROGRAM listman
USE themenu
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: opt
opt=choices()
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: The USE statement should be above the IMPLICIT NONE, but even then in the main program 'opt-choices()' has no implicit type according to the error message so should I insert assignment statements in my main program too in addition to my module? Thanks.

Comment: ok, but unfortunately I'm still getting an error saying "undefined reference to 'MAIN.'"  I'm a bit new to modules so I'm just curious can you tell if this is how to compile it? g95 listman.f95 themenu.f95 -o ba  - Does that seem right since maybe that is why I'm getting an error.

Comment: @EuropaDust: Looks fine to me. Are you sure that is exactly how you typed the command, and one of those files contains the program? The error is telling you the linker can't find the `main` function, which will be supplied by compiling `PROGRAM ...`.

Comment: @eriktous I think the file somehow got corrupted or something which is why it wasn't working for me, but now it is fine. Thanks so much!!